# Getting Value from a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, selectedvalue, radcombobox

I have had a look at numerous other threads on here that have a similar problem but have been unable to resolve my issue. I'm using the following code for my combobox:

```
<sq8:ComboBox runat="server" ID="cboAgree"><Items>
<sq8:ComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Agree"></sq8:ComboBoxItem>
<sq8:ComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Disagree"></sq8:ComboBoxItem>
</Items>
</sq8:ComboBox>
<sq:BindableControl runat="server" TargetControlID="cboAgree" DataField="Agreement"></sq:BindableControl>
```

I want to get the value selected (either "Agree" or "Disagree") and use that as a condition to hide/unhide a grid on my form:

```
   if (value == "Disagree") {
  commentsGrid.style.visibility = "visible";
  }else{
  commentsGrid.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
```

I've tried a number of things but it seems like the problem is to do with the way the form loads and the combobox doesn't have a value at that point. I always get an error that my comboBox "cboAgree" is null.

Could anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want - based on how you have the code structured in your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56293874/javascript-cannot-read-property-value-of-null-combobox-value), is to add an event handler to your combo box so that when the selected index is changed, you check the selection.

This scenario is covered in the [documentation here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/client-side-programming/events/onclientselectedindexchanged) but basically what you want to do is:

1. Add the following block inside your existing javascript:

```
function onSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) 
{
    var item = eventArgs.get_item();

    if (value == "Disagree") {
        commentsGrid.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        commentsGrid.style.display = "none";
    } 
}
```

I would suggest setting the `display` property to `none` and `block` instead of using `visibility` with `hidden` and `visible`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133064/5209435) covers the differences and why you should prefer using the `display` property in this instance.

2. Update your ComboBox to call the new Javascript method:

```
<sq8:ComboBox runat="server" ID="cboAgree"
onclientselectedindexchanged="onSelectedIndexChanged">
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the explanation!

It works but when i inspect the page, i get the following error 

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_item' of undefined`

Also, i think it's maybe to do with the loading of the form.. the default value in the dropdown is "Agree" so initially the grid is hidden, when i change it to "Disagree" it appears but if i change it back to "Agree" nothing happens. I think this may be where the error is occuring? Is there anything I can add to the javascript code that will help with this? I will show you what i have already..

Comment: `Sys.Application.add_load(FormLoad)  

 function FormLoad()
  {
    onSelectedIndexChanged(true);
  }  
`

This is what i have for loading the form.

Comment: Hmmm so that error message tells me that `eventArgs` is undefined. If you inspect the rendered HTML is your ComboBox rendered as a `Select` control with some `Option` elements inside it?

Comment: If the above is true then the following should work: https://pastebin.com/cc4DfA61.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks again for helping! I tried the code you've given and not get this error.. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined`

Comment: I inspected the HTML element when the form is running and it shows this.. https://pastebin.com/jmqN89DE

Comment: Very interesting, I've never used Telerik controls before but it will be something silly. Are you able to upload a sample project the reproduces the error that I can run on my machine to see what's going on?

Comment: I don't think I can. I'm using a framework called Cora Sequence. The project is a process stored within the framework and can't be ran outside of it.

Comment: I downloaded the [ASP.NET Ajax examples](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/) from the Telerik site after following [this documentation](http://kb.pnmsoft.com/help/combobox-control-overview) which when I clicked on "Client-side programming overview" took me back to the [Telerik documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/client-side-programming/overview). I know you've tried this method before and got the undefined error when trying to call `get_item`. I got the following working after downloading the samples [code here](https://pastebin.com/ysa6FiXQ).

Comment: @Adam I'm not really sure what else to suggest sorry. Maybe try using the [debugger](http://kb.pnmsoft.com/help/working-with-the-debugger) functionality or reach out to the support team [here](http://support.pnmsoft.com/_forms/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F) or [here](http://www.pnmsoft.com/resources/more-info/on-demand-knowledge/).

Comment: No problem @Matt ! Thanks for all your help. As i mentioned one of your methods worked partially so i can try and build on that! Thanks again! :)